# Square root of the determinant of AB+I where A, B are skew-symmetric

Tags: matrices, determinant, radicals

Imagine I have two skew-symmetric square matrices $A$, $B$. (So $A^\intercal = -A$, etc.) Now I am interested in the square root of the determinant of $AB+I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix,

$$ x = \sqrt{ \det \left( AB + I \right) } $$

As quick inspection for small matrices suggests that this $x$ is a *polynomial* of the elements of $A$ and $B$, for example for $3 \times 3$ matrices we find

$$ x =  1 - a_{12} b_{12} - a_{13} b_{13} - a_{23} b_{23} $$

and I checked this analytically for matrices up to $6 \times 6$. It reminds me of the pfaffian of a skew-symmetric matrix, which is also a 'square root of a determinant' but nonetheless a polynomial in the matrix elements.

Now my questions are:

- Does anyone know a proof that $x$ is a polynomial in the elements of $A$ and $B$, and if so, what is that polynomial?
- Does anyone know an efficient (so not $O(n!)$) algorithm to compute $x$?

Comment: If you multiply $AB+I $ with the skew-symmetric matrix $A $, you get the skew-symmetric matrix $ABA+A$. This shows that $\det\left (AB+I\right) $ is a quotient of two squares when $n$ is even. When $n $ is odd, you can go up one dimension. But this is clearly not the "right" proof. Great question!

Comment: By the proof of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity , it suffices to prove that $\det M $ is a square, where $M =  \begin{pmatrix}I_m & -A \\ B & I_n \end{pmatrix}$. Now, $M $ can be reduced easily to a skew-symmetric matrix (switch the first block column with the second one, then multiply said column by $-1$); this clears everything up.

Comment: @darijgrinberg There is no need to do any row/column operations. As $A$ and $B$ have identical sizes, we may begin with $M=\pmatrix{A&-I\\ I&B}$. Since the two sub-blocks at the bottom commute, $\det M=\det[(A)(B)-(-I)(I)]=\det(AB+I)$.

Comment: Thank you! As for a fast algorithm, now that $x$ is just the pfaffian of the matrix M that @user1551 defined, I can use the methods of Wimmer in this arXiv-post: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3440) to compute it fast.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity you are computing is very close to the *relative Pfaffian*, as found in for example Section 2 of [this](http://www.lesniewski.us/papers/papers_2/PfaffiansOnHilbertSpaces.pdf) paper.

Let $A,B$ be skew matrices acting on $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$, then there is something called the relative Pfaffian of $A$ with respect to $B$, denoted $
 \operatorname{Pf}(A,B)$,
which satisfies the relation
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname{Pf}(A,B)^{2} = \det(I - AB).
\end{equation}
(So I guess you would be interested in $\operatorname{Pf}(-A,B)$.)
An explicit formula for the relative Pfaffian is given in Definition II.7 on page 8 (or 355 if you prefer). It reads
\begin{equation}
 \operatorname{Pf}(A,B) = \sum_{S} \operatorname{Pf}(A_{S}) \operatorname{Pf}(B_{S}),
\end{equation}
where the sum runs over non-empty even subsets $S$ of $\{1, ..., 2n\}$, and where $A_{S}$ denotes the restriction of $A$ to the subspace spanned by $\{e_{j}\}_{j \in S}$.

It is furthermore proven that if $A$ is invertible, then the relation
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\operatorname{Pf}(A^{-1} -B)}{\operatorname{Pf}(A^{-1})} = \operatorname{Pf}(A,B).
\end{equation}
holds, (Proposition II.6, page 7).

Just in case that link rots, the article is called "*Pfaffians on Hilbert space*" and is written by Arthur Jaffe, Andrzej Lesniewski, and Jonathan Weitsman, published in the journal of functional analysis.

Comment: Are you sure you want to say "non-empty"?